# Javascript HTMLTableElement Class extension does not like this.rows

Tags: javascript, class, html-table, this

Try and do `this.rows` in a function in `class TableExtension extends HTMLTableElement`.

It Errors: `TypeError that is uncaught, "Illegal invocation"`

but `this.rows` IS NOT a function, so no `call`ing or `bind`ing won't be accepted.

I'm trying to use the mose pure and compact javascript as i can get, while still being readable

I'm using this so i can make a clear() function for a new table i'm creating:
Properties-Changer. so i can make an editor to a soon-to-be-made level format.

Please Tell me how to not get this error.

```
<script>
class TableExtended extends HTMLTableElement {
  constructor() {super();}
  errorHere() {console.log(this.rows.length);} 
  //anything to do with this.rows, really
}
document.registerElement("tbl-ext", TableExtended);
</script>
<tbl-ext id="helloTable"></tbl-ext>
<script>document.getElementById("helloTable").errorHere()</script>
```

Comment: How did you even create an instance of such a class? You can't exactly `new` any DOM element object...

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I... didn't... i registered it in document and used it in the document. as a html tag.

Comment: Fair enough. Please include a minimal (but complete) example that reproduces the problem. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I don't have time to look at the specs right now, but I thought you need to specify  the element you extend from in the `registerElement` something like that `document.registerElement('table-extension', { prototype: TableExtension, extends: 'table' });`. But it seems to be redundant, if you really need to do both the `class ... extend ...` and the `registerElement`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I cannot use a stack snippet, i need script elements before and after the table extension

Comment: @Alex-c I did a small peek in the specs and the examples. I think the way you wrote it should work in future, but the browsers most likely only implemented the basics of the API the would most likely not change and  what you observe is a bug of a logically not fully implemented API.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Which api?

Comment: @Alex-c The draft of the API [W3C: Custom Elements](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) and additional information on  [MDN: Custom Elements with Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements/Custom_Elements_with_Classes) `[...]Be advised that Custom Elements will be rewritten early 2016 by the W3C. It is very unlikely that any of the previous implementations will work in the future.[...]` In short do not use custom elements with classes until the specs are stable.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It is now late 2016... do you know what day it is?

Comment: @Alex-c first of all you tag the wrong person. And did you at least take a look at the links? The last update of the specs is from 13 October 2016 and it is still marked as Draft and Firefox does not event support `document.registerElement` without setting a flag in its settings. So even if the page on MDN says early 2016 the point is still true and the page is most likely not updated. But as you seem to know it better, good luck with getting a cross-browser solution that works and is stable.